# Modelling an unusual distribution observed with return on investment outcome

Tags: r, modeling, bayesian, mixture-distribution

This is a minor side-project I have been playing with and I wanted to see if anyone might have suggestions.

Problem. I used a dataset of loans with payment and borrower credit history (https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action), where each loan is a 36,60 month term. I am not so concerned with defaults vs. paid off (i.e. probability), I want to build a predictive model using loan/borrower characteristics to select loans and achieve the best possible return on investment.

I calculated the return on investment for each 36-month loan at term end (total payment recv'd / total loan amount at 36 months). https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4QsD.png

The distribution makes sense, i.e. a portion of loans default before the term is up leading to ROI ranging from near zero to ~1. Then other loans (most of them) are paid back with interest and have ROI >1.

I was wondering if there might be some suggestions about how to model such a thing? it seems to me like a mixture of two distributions and I was thinking Bayesian mixture modelling could account for this but there wouldn't be a clear parametric model to deal with this.

Comment: Questions about data modeling so not belong on Stack Overflow. You should ask such questions over at [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. SO is best for specific programming questions.